# Reading header-file of WAVE file

Tags: c++

I tried to read header-file of RIFF file. Everything looks like fine. But when I complied and ran, all file that I read had same data size. I don't know why?? I had ran some code about reading header_file of RIFF file but it wasn't different.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

#define SWAPPED_US(x) (((x) >> 8) | ((x) << 8))
#define SWAPPED_UL(x) ((((x) >> 24) & 0xff) | (((x) << 8) & 0xff0000) | (((x) >> 8) & 0xff00) | (((x) << 24) & 0xff000000))

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct {
    char ID [4];
    uint32_t Size;
    char Format [4];
    char SubID_1 [4];
    uint32_t SubSize_1;
    uint16_t AudioFmt;
    uint16_t Channel;
    uint32_t Frequency;
    uint32_t bytesRate;
    uint16_t BlockAlign;
    uint16_t BitsPerSample;
    char SubID_2 [4];
    uint32_t SubSize_2;
} RIFF_header;
#pragma pack(pop)

int getFileSize(FILE *inFile){
    int fileSize = 0;
    fseek(inFile,0,SEEK_END);
    fileSize=ftell(inFile);
    fseek(inFile,0,SEEK_SET);
    return fileSize;
}

int main ()
{
    FILE *fpoint;
    fpoint = fopen ("test.wav", "rb");
    RIFF_header *wave_file; wave_file = new RIFF_header;
    fread ((void*)wave_file, sizeof (RIFF_header), (size_t)1, fpoint); 


    wave_file->SubSize_2 = SWAPPED_UL(wave_file->SubSize_2); // I think it's big-endianess so we have to swap byte

    cout << "Size of file:      " << getFileSize(fpoint) << endl;
    cout << "Header:            " << wave_file->ID[0] 
                      << wave_file->ID[1] 
                      << wave_file->ID[2] 
                      << wave_file->ID[3] << endl;

    cout << "Format:            " << wave_file->Format[0] 
                      << wave_file->Format[1] 
                      << wave_file->Format[2] 
                      << wave_file->Format[3] << endl;

    cout << "Sub-chunk1 ID:         " << wave_file->SubID_1[0] 
                          << wave_file->SubID_1[1] 
                      << wave_file->SubID_1[2] 
                      << wave_file->SubID_1[3] << endl;

    cout << "Sub-chunk1 Size:   " << wave_file->SubSize_1 << endl;

    cout << "Audio Format:      " << wave_file->AudioFmt << endl;

    cout << "Channel:       " << wave_file->Channel << endl;

    cout << "Sample Rate:       " << wave_file->Frequency << endl;

    cout << "Byte Rate:         " << wave_file->bytesRate << endl;

    cout << "BlockAlign:        " << wave_file->BlockAlign << endl;

    cout << "Bits per sample:   " << wave_file->BitsPerSample << endl;

    cout << "Sub-chunk2 ID:         " << wave_file->SubID_2[0] 
                      << wave_file->SubID_2[1] 
                      << wave_file->SubID_2[2] 
                      << wave_file->SubID_2[3] << endl;
    cout << "Sub-chunk2 Size:   " << wave_file->SubSize_2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The subchunk sizes are stored in the header as little-endian, not big-endian.

Comment: And what is that magical size what you always get? Maybe the alignment of your header structure is off by some bytes and you read something else then you think (everything is skewed)?

Comment: that number is 2147418112 and after I swap bytes, it's 65407.

Comment: @Michael: Oh, my mistake. But after I fixed it, it's still a stranger number??

Answer (score 0):

check your `SubSize_1`... sometimes it's 16 bytes, sometimes 18.  If you have that wrong, your `SubSize_2` will be wrong too...

Comment: just depends on the application that wrote the WAV header... one was an older format but it's still generally acceptable

Comment: but I had downloaded some source code and it still remained the same :(